# Construct two arrow with css

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I'm want trying to accomplish something very, very similar to the below picture (two arrow) with CSS3 only. for next and prev.

[image]

What I need to know is how to construct what's shown in the above picture --  with CSS3 only?

Comment: I know you didn't ask for it (hence why this is a comment), but you could use charmap look -> ← →, then size and colour them accordingly :)

Comment: @jennifer Jolie: [See This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14480562/1516616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow">
    <div class="triangle-left"></div>
    <div class="tail left-arrow"></div>
</div>

<div class="arrow">
    <div class="triangle-right"></div>
    <div class="tail right-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow { position:relative; width: 130px; }
.triangle-left {
    border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
        float: left;
}
.triangle-right {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
        float: right;
}
.tail { width: 20px; height: 10px; position: absolute; background-color: green }
.tail.left-arrow { left: 40px; top: 15px }
.tail.right-arrow { right: 40px; top: 15px }
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/upyzU/)

Comment: Was about to post this idea too. Keep in mind you could layer another arrow over it that's 2px smaller and in the center of the arrow by using absolute positioning inside an relative DIV if you want to make it more complex. The same goes for the white 3d-ish glow. You can do this with multi-point gradient in CSS3. I would still advice using HTML5 Canvas or SVG tho. Drawing such a thing in JavaScript will be much better to understand and more flexible to edit and scale.

Comment: it is just an example I posted to show OP that how to achieve this. By the way thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to look as similiar to your given images as possible, you're propably best off using base64 images.

Google something like "image to base64": http://www.base64-image.de/

Upload your images and use the given base64 string as `background-image`.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.image {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,[...]');
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make use of a list and instead of bullets use arrows...For Example but not in CSS I'm sure you can do this in CSS.

```
<ul style="list-style-image: image(ltr 'arrow.png');">
<li dir='ltr'>My bullet is on the left!</li>
<li dir='rtl'>MY BULLET IS ON THE RIGHT!</li>
</ul>
```

It should be Something like this then you can align them in one line

```
⇒ My bullet is on the left!
!THGIR EHT NO SI TELLUB YM ⇐
```

Comment: @A.K Ok cool, But I believe I made it clear by saying -- "For Example but not in CSS I'm sure you can do this in CSS." I was giving him an idea.